# Duplicate data 1 to 2 to 1 : 1 sql join

Tags: sql

I have a problem with my query where it duplicate as follow

![result query][1]

As you can see my rows multiple the number of rows by itself,  as its the same id
do you know how to avoid it ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4uS8.png

```
SELECT 
distinct
tt.sourceId, tt.name,tt.date,
ts.content_plainText, ts.itemId, 
ttk.content_Plaintext, ttk.ticketId
FROM ticket_tickets as tt
inner join ticket_ticketSolutions ts
on tt.sourceId = ts.itemId
inner join ticket_ticketTasks ttk
on ts.itemId = ttk.ticketId
```

would it be possible to do like one rows equal 3 match result ??
I have even try the groupby id but won't work ?

Comment: That image shows one ticket joined to two solutions, which gives two rows *(1:2, not 1:1 as your question title claims)*.  Then again the join to Tasks is 1:2, so you end up with four rows.  Options appear to be:  If it's meant to be 1:1, fix the data.  If you only want one of the solutions and one of the tasks, you need to include how to make that choice in your question (how to choose which solution, and how to choose which task).  Or if you want both solutions and both tasks, you need to live with 4 rows or demonstrate in your question how you prefer them to be structured in your results.

Comment: that is the problem how to fix to 1 : 1 ?

Comment: `would it be possible to do like one rows equal 3 match result ??` - you can try use `group by` and `string_agg` if it is for sql server 2017+